# Why is my Asp.Net Form arriving empty when I post from Page to Page?

Tags: c#, form-post, forms, http-post

I have the following HTML Code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="frmSystem" method="post" action="target.aspx">
            <input id="txtTextField" type="text" />
            <input id="btnPost" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:frmSystem.submit();" type="button" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The target Page is coming up but the form that it is receiving is empty. I have a break point on my target.aspx page and while I can see a form, it's keys are empty and Request["txtTextField"] gives me nothing.

Any clue why?

Comment: MVC or webforms?  Looks like you are trying to use MVC.

Comment: What does your target form code look like? where is your breakpoint?

Comment: For now all I have in my target is this 

<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%
 string text = "";
    
 %>

and I'm obviously breaking on the only line of code. I use Watches to verify what I'm getting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC, the input names need to be set with the "name" attribute rather than "id".

Comment: I'm using webforms. No code behind, just a dll to handle some database access and the rest is scripts.

Comment: Thanks a lot actually, that was the solution.

Comment: You can use the `name` rather than `id` attribute as well as in the Asp.net web application or `webforms` too.

Answer (score 2):

You probably reset the form value in event handlers (such as page_load).

Comment: I usually blame users for stupid conducts, now the stupid was me. Thanks @manofseven2

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET 4.5 like me, use below hints

- **Disable auto Friendly URLs** in a Web Form project

  - settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off; // in RouteConfig.cs
- if you can:

  - remove action="CILandingPage.aspx" from form element
  - put a asp:button instead of normal button
  - set **PostBackUrl**="~/CILandingPage.aspx" on your asp:button

more resources with more detail that was useful to me

- [Disable auto Friendly URLs in a Web Form project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426839/disable-auto-friendly-urls-in-a-web-form-project)
- [http://www.mikesdotnetting.com request-form-is-empty-when-posting-to-aspx-page](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/293/request-form-is-empty-when-posting-to-aspx-page)

Comment: Importantly noted in your first link, you can set settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off inside RouteConfig.cs .  It is not necessary to disable auto friendly URLs entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to capture your Request.Form[] data in Application_BeginRequest on the Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //capture form data and preserve in query string
    if (Request.Form["txtTextField"]!= null)
    {
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl + "?txtTextField=" 
          + Request.Form["txtTextField"]);
    }
    //or preserve in Session variable
    if(Request.Form["txtTextField"]!=null)
    {
        Session["txtTextField"]=Request.Form["txtTextField"];
    }
}
```

The problem is that the form data is lost on the automatic redirect which is applied by friendlyUrls - if you store that data as something other than form data, it is unnecessary to turn off friendlyUrls or set AutoRedirectMode to RedirectMode.Off.