# When is Request.Form["name"] null and when an empty string?

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms

Why do the following result in a true if clause even though the textbox is empty and not even touched on a postback? :

```
<form action="Default.aspx" runat="server" method="post" id="newform">
<input type="text" id="name" runat="server"/>
</form>

<%
if (Request.Form["name"] != null) // Prints out "Name OK" on postback.
{
    Response.Write("<br/>");
    Response.Write("Name OK");
}
%>
```

Does the textbox actually contain an empty string ("") on a postback?

---

Why do the following result in a true if clause on the first page load but not on a postback? :

```
<form action="Default.aspx" runat="server" method="post" id="newform">
<input type="text" id="name" runat="server"/>
</form>

<%
if (Request.Form["name"] != "") // Prints out "Name OK" on first page load, but not on postback.
{
    Response.Write("<br/>");
    Response.Write("Name OK");
}
%>
```

To get a successful and expected result I have to use the following:

```
<form action="Default.aspx" runat="server" method="post" id="newform">
<input type="text" id="name" runat="server"/>
</form>

<%
if (Request.Form["name"] != null && Request.Form["name"] != "")
{
    Response.Write("<br/>");
    Response.Write("Name OK");
}
%>
```

Comment: disable auto friendly URL in asp.net 4.5 http://stackoverflow.com/a/40650127/184572

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**First, let me answer your question:**

The first page load is a GET, postbacks are a POST (hence the name **post**back). `Request.Form` is populated *only* if the page is loaded though a form POST.

- On the first page load, `Request.Form` is an empty collection. Since `Request.Form` is a `NameValueCollection`, [accessing a non-existent entry returns null](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d0bzeeb.aspx). Thus, `Request.Form["whatever"]` returns `null` on the first page load.
- After a postback, `Request.Form` is filled with values. Since HTTP POST does not know about `null` values, `Request.Form["whatever"]` returns an empty string for fields which are present but empty.

If you want to avoid the `x != null && x != ""` pattern, use [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) or the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx): `(x ?? "") != ""`.

---

**On the other hand, you could make your life a lot easier by just using the built-in WebForms features** instead of parsing `Request.Form` yourself:

```
<form runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="nameBox" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button Text="Do Postback" runat="server" />
</form>

<%
    if (nameBox.Text != "")
    {
        %><br />Name OK<%
    }
%>
```

Since [TextBox.Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text.aspx) defaults to `""`, there's no need to check for `null` here.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, but the answer not concerning my question/problem was unnecessary since I already know about the built-in WebForms features (That was also the reason why I didn't include the WebForms tag in the first place, but had to later on)

You may be wondering why I'm not using MVC instead then, but there's an easy answer to that: Learning HTML/javascript from scratch + MONO.

Comment: @Alex: Ah, ok, I understand. I'll leave the second part there anyway, just in case it might be helpful to someone reading the question in the future.

Answer (score 2):

`Request.Form` is [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx), which returns `null` if specified `key` is not found, returns value (which is an empty string) otherwise.

You may use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` method.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["name"]))
{
  Response.Write("<br/>");
  Response.Write("Name OK");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Request.Form["ControlName"]` returns `null` if Control is not present on form.

If Control is present, but it contains `null` or empty value, then `Request.Form["ControlName"]` will always return `String.Empty`.

So it's good practice, instead of comparing `(Request.Form["ControlName"] != null)`, use `(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["ControlName"]))`

Comment: Hi @NSNoob, why its return null if the control not present inside the form and append to outside in a page

Answer (score -1):

Base on this site: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/293/request-form-is-empty-when-posting-to-aspx-page

This is the answer. **Remark** this line:

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

in routeConfig.cs