# Disable auto Friendly URLs in a Web Form project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, url-routing, friendly-url

I created a C# web form project in Visual Studio 2013. When I run my `sample.aspx` page, the page automatically uses the `/sample` friendly URL routing.

I want to handle the routing myself manually and not let .NET to do it automatically. How can I disable the friendly URL feature. I don't want it uninstalled via NuGet, but only disabled in code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could also just set the AutoRedirect mode to Off. This kinda gives you the best of both worlds.

```
    public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your solution, open RouteConfig.cs (in the App_Start directory) and comment out or remove this line

```
    routes.EnableFriendlyUrls();
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Nothing I do make the friendly URL walk away :(

Comment: @IdanShechter - I wrestled with this same thing.  I couldn't figure out how it was still trying to redirect to the Friendly Urls, even with every part of it removed from my app.  Then I realized it was using HTTP 301 *permanent* redirect.  Clearing my browser cache fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

After uninstalling the NUGET package and deleting all the dll you must clear the browser cache

Comment: Worked for me.  Sometimes we just need to be reminded of the obvious. +1

Comment: I did not uninstall the pkg, but the hint on clearing the browser cache helped me a lot :-)